# Embedding finite 2-manifolds with zero curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry

I have learned that the surface of a torus (2D) can be embedded in a flat 4D manifold in such a way that its intrinsic (Riemannian) curvature is zero. A torus is a finite but unbounded manifold.

Here's the question:  The surface of a sphere is likewise finite and unbounded.  Is it also possible to embed it in a flat space in such a way that its curvature is zero?

Comment: I am fairly certain this is not possible, and I would say this is a standard example used for manifolds that cannot have a flat metric. Unfortunately, this is not my expertise and I do not have a source at hand. My first intuition would be that *if* it would be flat, there would exist a continuous unit vector field on the 2-sphere, which is not true by the "hairy ball theorem".

Comment: I think you mean extrinsic curvature (as you want to convey that it depends on the embedding). Did you also know that you could embed the torus in $\Bbb R^3$ such that its extrinsic curvature is zero? This is one of John Nash's great results, and a concrete embedding was constructed in I think 2011.

Comment: Many thanks.  Both of these comments have taught me something interesting.

Answer (score 3):

No. The Gauß-Bonnet theorem states that
$$ \int_M K d\mu = 2\pi \chi(M) ,$$ where $M$ is any closed manifold (i.e. compact, without boundary), $K$ is the Gaussian curvature and $\chi(M)$ is the Euler characteristic of $M$, an integer invariant depending only on the topology of $M$. In the case of the sphere, $\chi(M) = 2$, so the integral of the Gaussian curvature will be positive, hence it cannot be zero everywhere. Since the Gaussian curvature can be computed from the Riemannian curvature, this curvature also cannot be zero everywhere.

In the case of the torus $T$, $\chi(T) = 0$, hence this reasoning does not prevent us from embedding it in such a way that its curvature is zero everywhere.

Comment: Both the torus and the Klein bottle can be realized as quotients of the plane by group actions that preserve the Euclidean metric, which thus descends to flat metrics on each. On the other hand, the classification of compact surfaces shows that these are the only two with zero Euler characteristic and hence by this answer precisely the only surfaces that admit flat metrics. (But NB for nonorientable surfaces one needs to be a little careful about interpreting Gauss-Bonnet.)